# How to add CLIPC library in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

CLIPC is a library for interprocess communication in Java. I have downloaded it from https://sourceforge.net/project/platformdownload.php?group_id=255796

There were 2 folder inside the downloaded zip file.

1)Exe folder contain clipc.dll and clipc.jar and one other folder

2)source folder contain clipc-java and clipc-native

I dont know How to add CLIPC library in eclipse, I want to run different ipc methods and see result

please help me,thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is go to your project, right click, navigate to "build path", then click on "configure build path". then on the right, click on "add external jars" and choose the  clipc.jar file